# ¿Cómo buscar un caracter en string Python?

Tags: python, string, busqueda

Estoy haciendo un juego del ahorcado con Python (3.7). Ya casi está completo, pero tengo un detalle que no logro solucionar aún.

```
index = palabra.find(letra)
aux[index] = letra
```

Lo cual funciona a la perfección porque hace la búsqueda de la letra (o palabra) dentro de la palabra original, y devuelve la posición en la que se encuentra (para ello ocupo una lista«aux», para poder reemplazar en posiciones). 
Esto no me resulta tan útil para cuando un caracter se repite, ya que el método find() devuelve la posición de la primera coincidencia.

Quisiera saber si existe algún método para encontrar las posiciones de todas las coincidencias y reemplazarlas al tiempo que el jugador acierte dicha letra.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Se me ocurrió hacer esto:
`index = palabra.find(letra)`
`aux[index] = letra`
`index = palabra.rfind(letra)`
`aux[index] = letra`

Ahora ya funciona para palabras que tienen una letra repetida (solo dos veces). Aún así, espero haya otro método para hacerlo para TODAS las coincidencias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar funciones del módulo `re` de expresiones regulares.

Por ejemplo, supongamos que tienes la palabra a adivinar en la variable `palabra`:

```
palabra ="Supercalifragilisticoespialidoso"
```

y que tienes otra variable para la "pista" a mostrar, que es una lista de caracteres de igual longitud a la original, con "-" en las letras que aún no ha adivinado. Esta lista puede inicializarla así:

```
pista = ["-"]*len(palabra)
```

y mostrarla así:

```
print("".join(pista))
```

que en este caso mostrará:

```
--------------------------------
```

Ahora el usuario ha introducido una letra, pongamos la "s", y la tienes en la variable `letra`:

```
letra = "s"
```

y lo que quieres es sustituir todos los "-" de la variable `pista` cuya posición coincida con una en `palabra` donde esté esa `letra`, por la correspondiente letra.

El siguiente código (que luego explico) lo haría. Requiere un `import re` al inicio del programa:

```
for c in re.finditer(letra, palabra, re.IGNORECASE):
     pista[c.start():c.end()] = list(c.group())
```

La función `finditer()` va buscando todas las apariciones de `letra` en `palabra` (en realidad es mucho más general pues lo que busca son expresiones regulares) ignorando si es mayúscula o minúscula. Para cada vez que encuentre un encaje, retorna un objeto de tipo `match` que es el que recojo en la variable `c` sobre la que itero.

Este objeto `match` tiene varios métodos, como `c.group()` que me devuelve la letra encontrada en `palabra` (puede ser "s" o "S"), o `c.start()` y `c.end()`, que me devuelve  los índices en que empieza y termina la subcadena encontrada (aquí lo estamos usando para una sola letra, pero en general puede encontrar cadenas de cualquier longitud, por eso hacen falta ambos índices).

Entonces, en cada iteración, sustituyo todas las letras entre la posición de inicio y la de fin por las letras encontradas. En cada iteración será una sola letra en este caso la que se sustituirá por lo que podría haber escrito:

```
for c in re.finditer(letra, palabra, re.IGNORECASE):
     pista[c.start()] = c.group()
```

que en este caso hace lo mismo y es mucho más fácil de entender. Pero en el caso general, "letra" podría ser cualquier subcadena y también la encontraría. Quizás esto dé para una variante nueva del ahorcado en la que el jugador tenga que descubrir parejas contiguas de letras :-)

Una vez hecha la sustitución, al imprimir de nuevo `pista` tendríamos:

```
print("".join(pista))
```

---

```
S---------------s-----s-------s-
```

### Otra forma

Entiendo que el código anterior es quizás demasiado complejo para una situación tan simple como ésta, por lo que ofrezco otra solución más convencional. Simplemente se itera por las letras de `palabra`, a la vez que tenemos sus índices, gracias a `enumerate()`. Para cada letra que coincida con la buscada, ya que tenemos su índice, lo usamos para sustituir en la `pista`:

```
for i, l in enumerate(palabra):
    if l.lower() == letra.lower():
       pista[i] = l
```

Comment: Eres como un dios para mí a partir de ahora. Ya había pensado en usar las regex (aunque no sabía exactamente cómo), pero quería ver si existía algo mas sencillo, y me lo demostraste con ese "doble for" nunca se me hubiera ocurrido. Mil gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tenes que usar la función replace, que remplaza todas las cadenas que quieras de una sola vez.

```
palabra= palabra.replace("cadena a buscar", "por lo que queres remplazar")
```

Answer (score 0):

Para buscar la cantidad de ocurrencias que hay de una letra en una frase, puedes usar:

```
>>> frase = "Esta es una frase de prueba"
>>> frase.count('a') # Cantidad de 'a'
4
```

Con el cálculo anterior ya podrías hacer un `for` o `while` que recorra toda la frase hasta que encuentre las `n` ocurrencias, previamente calculadas, de la cadena buscada.

O, si bien, no existe un método nativo para encontrar los índices de las ocurrencias, una forma pytónica de hacerlo sería:

```
>>> [idx for idx, x in enumerate(frase) if x=='a'] # indices de todas las 'a'
[3, 10, 14, 26]
```

Finalmente si quieres reemplazar todas las ocurrencias, como mencionaron en  otra respuesta, entonces el método replace es lo que necesitas.

```
>>> frase.replace('a', '*')
'Est* es un* fr*se de prueb*'
```