# Cómo detectar una letra en una palabra, en Python?

Tags: python

la consigna de mi problema me pide crear un menú de opciones donde una de las opciones sea escribir manualmente el nombre de 20 provincias, el problema viene cuando me pide que al finalizar de escribirlas, me diga cuantas de ellas empiezan con la letra A. Es mi primer año y recién empezamos a programar, por lo que nuestros conocimientos son muy básicos

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo buscar un caracter en string Python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/272517/c%c3%b3mo-buscar-un-caracter-en-string-python)

Comment: Qué has intentado hacer? Sube el código de lo que has intentado a tu pregunta y explica qué es lo que no te funciona o no entiendes.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Si guardas las palabras dentro de una lista esto te podria servir:

```
palabras = ['ABC', 'CBC', 'ars', 'pqr', '0123']

for palabra in palabras:
    if palabra[0].lower() == 'a':
        print(palabra)
```

Comment: Sin una explicacion de que hace esto, para un principiante, es poco productivo. Mas alla de eso, tratamos de no resolver ejercicios, si no ayudar a resolverlos...

Answer (score 0):

No te diré la solución, pero te daré una idea de como hacerlo.

Primero debes elegir una estructura de datos para ir almacenando las palabras, por ejemplo una lista, al terminar tu lista tendría 20 palabras, desde la posición 0 a la 19.

Una vez tengas las lista completa, haces un ciclo que recorra la lista, es decir que revise palabra por palabra, y en cada repetición del ciclo, crearás un condicional que revise en cada repetición la primera letra de la palabra (te recomiendo convertir la palabra en mayúscula, porque puede que el usuario ingrese algunas mayúsculas y algunas minúsculas, así evitas tener que hacer dos condicionales para revisar si empieza con 'a' o con 'A'), si se cumple la condición imprimes esa posición de la lista, y eso sería todo.

Si tienes alguna duda con algún concepto, algún error de sintaxis o no sabes como manejar bien el ciclo o las listas, me dices que quedo atento :)